# Як правильно: "у дусі" чи "у духові"?

Tags: вживання-слів

Чи є певне правило, яке дає чітку відповідь на це питання: як правильно "у дусі" чи "у духові"? І все ж, як правильно?)

Comment: Про всяк випадок: на цьому сайті дуже заохочуються спроби самостійного дослідження теми. Це не означає, що відвідувач має розв'язати своє питання самостійно (тоді б не було запитання). Але бажано принаймні спробувати й написати, на чому саме спинилися (наприклад: «у такому-то джерелі написано _у дусі_, а в такому-то — _у духові_, і тому я не можу зробити остаточний висновок самостійно»).

Comment: На сайтах мереж Stack Exchange ви, як той хто ставить питання, **зобов'язані** зробити максимальний research, перш ніж ставити питання. Питання такого роду належать гугл пошуку і відповідь до них знаходиться за 20 секунд. Інакше, ваші питання будуть закриватися та вони будуть отримувати даунвоути.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Коротко — для слова *дух*:

- У давальному відмінку можливі закінчення *-ові* та *-у*: *відповідає духові*, *відповідає духу*.
- У місцевому відмінку зазвичай вживають закінчення *-і* (*у дусі*). Закінчення *-ові* (*у духові*) формально не заборонене, але його вживають рідко.

#### Докладніше про давальний відмінок

З «Українського правопису» 2019:

> У давальному відмінку однини іменники другої відміни мають
> закінчення -ові, -еві (-єві), -у (-ю).
>
> 1. Закінчення -ові (у твердій групі), -еві (у мішаній групі та в м’якій
>    після приголосного), -єві (у м’якій групі після голосного та апострофа)
>    мають іменники чол. роду (за винятком зазначених у п. 2 б): ба́тькові,
>    ве́летневі, дире́кторові, ді́дові, добро́дієві, журавле́ві, ма́йстрові, Петро́ві,
>    побрати́мові, працівнико́ві, секретаре́ві, Сергі́єві, си́нові, солов’є́ві, та́тові,
>    това́ришеві, шахтаре́ві; буди́нкові, бу́кові, дро́тові, запа́сові, ки́лимові,
>    набо́рові, пала́цові; га́єві, ка́меневі, кра́єві, пне́ві; доще́ві, пла́че́ві, плаще́ві та ін. Ці ж іменники набувають і закінчення -у (у твердій і мішаній групах), -ю (у м’якій групі): дире́ктору, ма́йстру, Петру́, ве́летню, Віта́лію, журавлю́, солов’ю́; буди́нку, бу́ку, дро́ту, запа́су, ки́лиму, пала́цу; га́ю, ка́меню, кра́ю.
>
> [Зазначу, що п. 2 б — це про іменники на *-ів* (як-от: *рів*, *Київ*, *острів*), тому він не стосується слова *дух*.]

Зазначу, що деякі мовознавці та літературні редактори вважають закінчення *-ові* в давальному відмінку  (звісно, для тих випадків, де його дозволено) притаманнішим українській мові, ніж закінчення *-у*. І в тексті «Правопису» це закінчення справді наведено першим, наче воно основне. У корпусі «ГРАК-14», однак, якщо шукати *відповідає духові* і *відповідає духу*, то кількість приблизно однакова.

#### Місцевий відмінок

Знов-таки, з «Українського правопису» 2019:

> У місцевому відмінку однини іменники другої відміни мають закінчення
> -і (-ї), -ові, -еві (-єві), -у (-ю).
>
> 1. Закінчення -і (після голосного та апострофа — -ї) мають:
>
>    1) іменники чол. роду (переважно безсуфіксні) — назви неістот: в а́кті, в ду́сі, у комп’ю́тері, у байра́ці, у бе́резі, у ґру́нті, у декре́ті, у телефо́ні, на ду́бі, на мі́сяці, на по́версі, на поро́зі, на столі́, на язиці́́́, по асфа́льті, по фунда́менті, при дні, при столі́, при хара́ктері;

І ще:

> 3. Закінчення -ові у твердій групі, -еві (після голосного та апострофа — -
>    єві) у м’якій та мішаній групах мають:
>
>    1. іменники чол. роду — переважно назви істот: на/при ба́тькові, на/при
>       ліснико́ві, на/при водіє́ві, на/при вчи́телеві, на/при коне́ві, на/при това́ришеві;

Отже в місцевому відмінку для слова *дух* рекомендовано (*-і*), а *-ові* — це радше для істот. У «ГРАК-14» для *в/у дусі* 6529 траплянь, а для *в/у духові* — 74 трапляння.

Comment: перепрошую, ви без жодного коментаря до питання вирішили просто відповісти?

Comment: @P.Vowk, Ви натякаєте, що я мав спочатку написати про бажаність самостійного дослідження? Мабуть, Ви маєте рацію.

Comment: Дякую за вичерпну відповідь!